# Using Serial Port as a Terminal Interface with VMware?

Tags: command-line, vmware, putty

I have the following configuration setup:

Ubuntu 12.10 os a virtual machine using VMware.
Host OS is Windows 8.1
Terminal Program is [Putty](http://www.putty.org/) as a Serial Terminal in Windows 8.1

**Process:**

Ubuntu VMware machine: hardware is Serial Port 2 using `\\.\pipe\com_1`
Windows 8.1, Putty is set to Serial line `\\.\pipe\com_1 Speed 115200`

On a terminal in Ubuntu:

```
billm@ubuntu:~$ echo hello > /dev/ttys1
bash: /dev/ttys1: Permission denied
```

Nothing shows up on the putty terminal window at Windows 8.1

What can I do to prove that Ubuntu can talk serially to putty?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question a bit, its not clear what you are trying to achieve. If you want to connect to the Ubuntu VM running on the host, did you try `ssh`ing  through putty?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `sudo` to run the command,

```
$ sudo echo hello > /dev/ttys1
```

or changing the permissions of the device to be readable/writeable by anyone and then running the command as user:

```
$ sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttys1
$ echo hello > /dev/ttys1
```

Note that you may need to run `chmod` every time the device is created to interact with it as a user.

Comment: This may be better as a comment

Comment: Excuse me, it was intended to solve the problem alltogether. Have I misunderstood the issue?

Comment: Ok I will rephrase: This answer may solve the issue, however you may wish to expand on this answer. Such as explaining what the command does. If you do not wish to do so, this is probably better off being a comment. If it solves the issue, you could try moving it down to an answer (but expand the answer).

Comment: How does it look now?

Comment: It looks much better